# Let user know when other person is typing

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

In our chat, can we have a little spiral or something that lets you know when the person you are talking to is typing? It would make Chat a lot more efficient...

Something like a message saying:

```
USER is typing...
```

Google and a lot of other chat websites have an indicator to tell whether the other person is typing, and that would be really neat to incorporate into chat.stackoverflow.com.

:)

Comment: This would help if the other person is typing an response, and you understand and say you got it, ask another question, but the other person still clicks enter right after your response. If we knew that the other person was typing, it would make chat rooms less messy, and more efficient.

Comment: *user is typing* ... waits ... *user is typing* ... still waiting ... *nothing* ... ... should I still wai*user is typing*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is a pretty unnecessary feature to be honest.

> It would make Chat a lot more efficient...

How so? You didn't exactly explain that in your question.

How would it be handled when multiple people are typing at the same time?

What exactly does it specifically add that would be beneficial?

The `Person X is typing...` indicator is a convenience for individual conversation between two or more people, say, through SMS, or Google Hangouts, or whatever. I don't see Chat on Stackoverflow to serve the same purpose. To me, it is more of a dynamic message board of sorts. It doesn't really matter if a user is typing out a message.

Is it really worth the SO devs working on such a small Quality of Life feature? If you can even argue it to be one..